# Lightning pagination with InlineEdit

Tags: lightning

Hi everyone am trying to implement pagination in Lightning tried so far..

Apex:

```
public class contactpagination {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> showContacts(){
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        contactList = [Select Id, Name, Title, Email, MobilePhone, Fax, AccountId From Contact LIMIT 25];
        return contactList;
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static String savecontacts(List<contact> conlist){
        System.debug(conlist);
        System.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        update conlist;
        system.debug(conlist);
        return 'hi';
    } 
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="contactpagination" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <!-- Attribute Declration For Pagination -->
    <aura:attribute name="ContactData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    
     <aura:attribute name="isSending" type="boolean" />
    
    <!-- Attribute Declration For Pagination -->
    <aura:attribute name="PaginationList" type="Contact"/>
    <aura:attribute name="startPage" type="Integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="endPage" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalRecords" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pageSize" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <!-- Attribute Declration For Pagination End-->
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
    
    <!-- Spinner Start, show the loading screen while 
         Client side controller(JS) is communicating with Server Side(APEX) controller -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isSending}">
        <div class="slds-spinner_container">
            <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--large" role="alert">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
    <!-- Spinner End -->
    
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity" 
                      title="Description of icon when needed">
                    
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" 
                    title="Pagination Demo">Pagination Demo</h1>
                <p class="slds-text-body_small slds-line-height_reset">
                   By - Anusha </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium" >
        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.PaginationList }" class="slds-m-top_medium"
                             columns="{! v.columns }" 
                             keyField="id"
                             onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"
                             onsave="{!c.handleSave }"/>    
        <br/>
        <lightning:buttonGroup >
            <lightning:button label="Previous" disabled="{!v.startPage == 0}"  
                              onclick="{!c.previous}" variant="brand"
                              iconName='utility:back'/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <lightning:button label="Next" disabled="{!v.endPage >= v.totalRecords}" 
                              onclick="{!c.next}" variant="brand"
                              iconName='utility:forward' iconPosition='right'/>
        </lightning:buttonGroup>
    </div>  
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        // Set the columns of the Table 
        component.set('v.isSending',true);
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', sortable : true, editable:'true'},
            {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text', sortable : true, editable:'true'},
            {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email', sortable : true ,editable:'true'},
            {label: 'Mobile Phone', fieldName: 'MobilePhone', type: 'phone', sortable : true,editable:'true'},
        ]);
        helper.doFetchContact(component);
    },
    getSelectedName: function (component, event) {
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        // Display that fieldName of the selected rows
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            //alert("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Name);
        }
    },
    next: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.next(component, event);
    },
    previous: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.previous(component, event);
    },
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    /*
     * Initially this Method will be called and will fetch the records from the Salesforce Org 
     * Then we will hold all the records into the attribute of Lightning Component
     */
    doFetchContact : function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.showContacts');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS' && component.isValid()){
                var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
                // hold all the records into an attribute named "ContactData"
                component.set('v.ContactData', response.getReturnValue());
                // get size of all the records and then hold into an attribute "totalRecords"
                component.set("v.totalRecords", component.get("v.ContactData").length);
                // set star as 0
                component.set("v.startPage",0);
                
                component.set("v.endPage",pageSize-1);
                var PaginationList = [];
                for(var i=0; i< pageSize; i++){
                    if(component.get("v.ContactData").length> i)
                        PaginationList.push(response.getReturnValue()[i]);    
                }
                component.set('v.PaginationList', PaginationList);
                component.set('v.isSending',false);
            }else{
                alert('ERROR');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    /*
     * Method will be called when use clicks on next button and performs the 
     * calculation to show the next set of records
     */
    next : function(component, event){
        var sObjectList = component.get("v.ContactData");
        var end = component.get("v.endPage");
        var start = component.get("v.startPage");
        var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
        var Paginationlist = [];
        var counter = 0;
        for(var i=end+1; i<end+pageSize+1; i++){
            if(sObjectList.length > i){
                Paginationlist.push(sObjectList[i]);
            }
            counter ++ ;
        }
        start = start + counter;
        end = end + counter;
        component.set("v.startPage",start);
        component.set("v.endPage",end);
        component.set('v.PaginationList', Paginationlist);
    },
    /*
     * Method will be called when use clicks on previous button and performs the 
     * calculation to show the previous set of records
     */
    previous : function(component, event){
        var sObjectList = component.get("v.ContactData");
        var end = component.get("v.endPage");
        var start = component.get("v.startPage");
        var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
        var Paginationlist = [];
        var counter = 0;
        for(var i= start-pageSize; i < start ; i++){
            if(i > -1){
                Paginationlist.push(sObjectList[i]);
                counter ++;
            }else{
                start++;
            }
        }
        start = start - counter;
        end = end - counter;
        component.set("v.startPage",start);
        component.set("v.endPage",end);
        component.set('v.PaginationList', Paginationlist);
    },
    
    handleSave: function(cmp, event, helper){
        var action = cmp.get("c.savecontacts");
        var conList = cmp.get("v.PaginationList");
        var draftList = event.getParam('draftValues');
        console.log('draftValues-> ' + JSON.stringify(draftList));
        console.log('conList->' + JSON.stringify(conList));
        console.log(conList);
        action.setParams({conlist: draftList});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log('hi'); 
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for the code; but... **FIrstly**, please help the volunteers here to help you by previewing your post to make sure it is easily readable before you submit it. Use the Markdown formatting available in the editor. In the future, please format your code so that it is easy to read and follow - use the three backticks ("```") to set apart your code, and use consistent indenting. If your code is hard to read, it is hard to follow, which makes it hard for someone to help. *(Your question has already been edited to format the code properly.)*

Comment: **Secondly**, please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _'...a question post should include 1) A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help). plus ... 3) and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.'_ Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357584/edit) your question to add that info.